How to convert a timestamp a number in Oracle SQL
I have a timestamp as follows
'01:54:45' in a column and I want to change it to a int or a bigint for e.g 1809384, just a random number for the same timestamp i.e if the timestamp is same as the one in eg then it should be converted into a bigint as I have mentioned. Can anyone please help me with this, I want to calculate avg time taken by a workflow to complete in a span of 2, 3 days. Subsequently once I get the avg I want to convert it back to the given timestamp format. For eg if the avg is 728638 I want to it to convert back to '01:03:23'.
I tried to_number(to_char('01:54:45', 'HHMISS')) but it's not working.

So, '01:54:45' is a duration, and that duration is stored as a string? And you want to get the average duration of several rows?

Does "in a span of 2, 3 days" mean the 'hours' part can be more than 23 - if it can represent 48 or 72 hours etc.? If so can it be more than 100? If it is always less than a day then you can use date conversions, but it's unclear.

A duration is called an INTERVAL in SQL. So the natural way to do this would be to store the data as an interval (INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND in Oracle) and then get the average:
select avg(duration) from mytable where ...

You can convert a duration stored in a string column as 'HH:MM:SS' with
to_dsinterval('0 ' || duration_string)

However, Oracle has not been able to sum and average intervals up to Oracle 21c. This is only possible as of Oracle 23c.
In older versions you would convert the duration to seconds instead and work with these:
with
  durations as
  (
    select
      to_number(substr(duration_string, 1, 2)) * 3600 +
      to_number(substr(duration_string, 4, 2)) *   60 +
      to_number(substr(duration_string, 7, 2)) as seconds
    from mytable
    where ...
  )
select numtodsinterval(avg(seconds), 'second')
from durations;

NUMTODSINTERVAL converts the seconds into an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, as you might have guessed. If you don't want to display the result as an interval, but as a string in the original format, use TO_CHAR. Unfortunately though, this function doesn't work with intervals in Oracle, so you must add a dummy date:
to_char(date '1900-01-01' + numtodsinterval(avg(seconds), 'second'), 'hh24:mi:ss')

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/B2kaYVLw

To me, it looks as if "timestamp" is stored as a string which represents hours:minutes:seconds. If that's so, one option might be to

convert it to seconds by extracting every part of it and multiply with appropriate value
once you got seconds, calculate average (that's OK, because result will represent average number of seconds)
convert that value back to seconds, hours and minutes (again by applying appropriate calculation)
finally, compose the result by concatenating previously calculated values

Here's an example:
Sample data; it is about 6 minutes less and more than 2 hours, which means that the final result should be "2 hours 0 minutes" and "(46 + 18) / 2 = 64  / 2 = 32 seconds".
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select '01:54:46' from dual union all
  4     select '02:06:18' from dual
  5    ),

Query begins here:
  6  convert_to_number as
  7    (select col,
  8         to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1)) * 60 * 60 +
  9         to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2)) * 60 +
 10         to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 3)) to_num
 11     from test
 12    ),
 13  calculate_average as
 14    (select avg(to_num) avg_tn
 15     from convert_to_number
 16    ),
 17  hms as
 18    (select avg_tn,
 19       avg_tn / (60 * 60) c_hour,
 20       --
 21       mod(avg_tn / (60 * 60), 1) * 60 c_min,
 22       --
 23       mod(mod(avg_tn / (60 * 60), 1) * 60, 1) * 60 c_sec
 24     from calculate_average
 25    )
 26  select lpad(trunc(c_hour), 2, '0') ||':'||
 27         lpad(trunc(c_min) , 2, '0') ||':'||
 28         lpad(trunc(c_sec)  , 2, '0') as result
 29  from hms;

RESULT
--------
02:00:32

SQL>


You can convert each time value to a DATE and then find the difference from the DATE at midnight on the same date and average that value and convert it back to your time format:
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
         + AVG(TO_DATE(ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')),
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS avg_ts
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ts) AS
  SELECT '01:54:45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '01:55:15' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



AVG_TS




01:55:00



fiddle

If the values will always be less than a day, so the hour part is always between 00 and 23 - which isn't clear from the wording of the question - then another date-based approach is to convert the string to a date and back to the number of seconds into the day that represents, using the SSSSS format element, which is "Seconds past midnight (0-86399).", initially as a string and then as a number:
select time_str,
  to_date(time_str, 'HH24:MI:SS') as time_dat,
  to_char(to_date(time_str, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS') as sec_str,
  to_number(to_char(to_date(time_str, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS')) as sec_num
from your_table




TIME_STR
TIME_DAT
SEC_STR
SEC_NUM




01:54:45
2024-04-01 01:54:45
06885
6885


00:12:01
2024-04-01 00:12:01
00721
721



(If you only provide the time components to to_date() it defaults to the first day of the current month.)
Once each string is converted to a number in that range you can get the average:
select
  avg(
    to_number(to_char(to_date(time_str, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS'))
  ) as avg_sec_num
from your_table




AVG_SEC_NUM




3803



And then convert that back to a date, and then back to a string:
select
  to_char(
    to_date(
      avg(
        to_number(to_char(to_date(time_str, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS'))
      ),
      'SSSSS'
    ),
    'HH24:MI:SS'
  ) as avg_time_str
from your_table




AVG_TIME_STR




01:03:23



fiddle
